# OAuth Client Credentials flow for external services - token expiration

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials, external-services

I'm trying to connect to Marketo REST API via an external service leveraged in a flow, using the client credentials external credential and a named credential. Here is Marketo's [doc on authentication](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/authentication/#creating_an_access_token)

My flow works fine for an hour, but then the access token from Marketo expires and Salesforce doesn't fetch a new one, so my flow in Salesforce starts showing the error it gets from Marketo's API that the access token is invalid. Here is where it calls the external service when debugging my flow:
[image: flow debug error]

I can get it working again for another hour by editing the client id and client secret in the principal of my external credential, then changing them back, which seems to make it fetch a new token from the identity endpoint.

Is there a way to set an expiration time for tokens in the external credential, so it knows when to fetch a fresh token? Or perhaps apex I can invoke that forces it to fetch a new token from the identity URL? Marketo doesn't support refresh tokens unfortunately.

Comment: The token expiration is set by the system that issues it (in this case Marketo) rather than the calling system (Salesforce). What I've seen before is to cache access tokens in the session cache, and then when retrieving this if it is expired call the authentication endpoint again. I've seen this written in Apex before.

Comment: ...or if the volume of requests isn't high, simply ask for a fresh token every time you need one.